# SwiftUI reading a Core Data entity into a []

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a Core Data entity with the attributes "latitude" and "longitude," and I want to read its data into a [] for MapKit's MapAnnotation. I understand how to use ForEach to iterate through an entity to create a View, as seen in the sample below, but I don't understand how I read data into a [].

```
ForEach(stores.reversed()) { store in
    HStack {
        Text("\(store.name ?? "")")
        Spacer()
        Text("\(store.latitude, specifier: "%.3f"),")
        Text("\(store.longitude, specifier: "%.3f")")
    }
}
```

"locations" is a variable containing coordinates for MapAnnotation.
"stores" is a variable containing the fetched entity data.
"Location" is an identifiable for the CLLocationCoordinate2D format.

Below is what I've attempted, but clearly it is wrong. How do I iterate through "stores" correctly?

```
@State var locations: [Location] = [
    for store in stores {
        Location(coordinate: .init(latitude: store.latitude, longitude: store.longitude))
    }
]
```

Comment: Source code: https://github.com/thorskjold/BestBefore/tree/main/Shared/Views

Answer (score 0):

A for loop inside of array brackets does nothing because it doesn’t return anything. I think what you're looking for is `.map`

```
@State var locations: [Location] = stores.map { store in
  Location(
    coordinate: .init(
      latitude: store.latitude, 
      longitude: store.longitude
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! However when I attempt this, I get the error "Cannot use instance member 'stores' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" on the @State line.

Comment: yeah, if stores is another State variable (i can't tell from your question it's not visible) then you can't use it in an initialize value like that. You would most likely want to set the locations to the value you want using .onAppear in the view